# Ayuda con usuario que formuló la misma pregunta otra vez por no tener acceso a su cuenta original

Tags: soporte

El usuario `user31261` abrió la siguiente pregunta: [¿Cómo hago rotar una imagen en php?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/51904/c%C3%B3mo-hago-rotar-una-imagen-en-php). Pero, luego parece que perdió acceso a esa cuenta, por lo que bajo otra cuenta (`Jair Vasquez`) comenzó a hacer ediciones a la pregunta (que de paso me parece que no han debido ser aprobadas en la cola de revisión).

En todo caso, ahora esta persona con su segunda cuenta vuelve a abrir la misma pregunta de forma separada [¿como hago rotar una imagen en php?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/52238/como-hago-rotar-una-imagen-en-php).

Como su primera pregunta nunca podrá marcarse como solucionada, pero a la vez ya recibió respuestas que tal vez le sean útil a él o a otras personas, ¿hay manera de hacer un tipo de "merge" de las 2 preguntas para que no se pierdan ninguna de las respuestas, pero para evitar tener una pregunta huerfana?

Comment: Ya entendí. ¿No se puede marcar la primera duplicada de la segunda? La primera es la que tiene las respuestas, pero ya no se puede marcar como solucionada.

Comment: @toledano: El problema es que la primera pregunta ya tiene 4 votos de cierre por ser damasiada amplia. No sé como reaccionará si le agrego el 5to voto por duplicado. ¿Lo marcará como duplicado, o simplemente irá con la mayoría de los votos y se marcará como cerrada por ser demasiada amplia. Pero, en efecto, tal vez eso sea lo único que se necesite.

Comment: Mejor hay que reportarla.

Comment: Lo marcara como demasiada amplia... (votos mayores)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En relación a las dos cuentas, el usuario debería solicitar la combinación (merge) de ambas cuentas. Para ello, debes seguir el enlace "Contacto" que se encuentra al pie de todas las páginas de este sitio y hacer la solicitud.

En cuanto a la combinación de ambas preguntas, me parece que sí es posible, pero para ello deben intervenir los moderadores por lo cual hay que "reportar" la pregunta. Ya que se ha creado este hilo, sería muy útil incluir el enlace al mismo.

Comment: Efectivamente. Primero se marca una como duplicada de la otra y después se puede proceder a hacer el _merge_.